# How to add provisioning account to Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

"No Device Registered"
"Creating a provisioning profile requires one or more devices to be registered with your team.  Connect a device to your Mac to add it to your team."

I am getting this message when archiving my ios app developed with ionic v1. I do not have an Apple device to be connected. Is it possible to skip this error and get .ipa of my app without connecting any device? if so how?

[image]

I am using Xcode 7.1 and mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan

Comment: There won't be any use of that .ipa because that won't install on any iOS device. You need a developer account.

Comment: am I not able to get .ipa without a developer account? @Vakas

Comment: @Amila Perera It is not possible. You have to create a Provisioning profile for your application.

Comment: @AmilaPerera No, you can't. You need a developer account.

Answer (score 1):

U can register for a free developer account at developer.apple.com,
after registration in Xcode general settings there is a field called team just add your account also check Automatically manage signin that should solve the issue.